# unable to adjust the footer padding in a vuetify v-data-table

Tags: css, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I have a pretty standard veutify v-data-table with the standard pagination footer. I need to offset the footer items so they're not underneath an element that floats above them.

I've tried:

```css
#table  .v-data-footer {
  padding: 0 100px !important;
}
```

and

```css
.v-data-footer {
  padding: 0 100px !important;
}
```

but neither way worked. We're using SCSS styling, not SASS, so the vue docs about footer-padding don't seem to help.

I've got reputation to spare, so the best answer will get 50 point bounty when 48 hours have passed.

**Edit**: I’m using Vuetify version 2.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the deep functionality to add scope to the class.

```
::v-deep  .v-data-footer {
  padding: 0 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your style to `padding: 100px 0 !important;`. If this doesn't work, that means because of css specificity your style is not getting updated and you have to increase the specificity of your selector. For example  if the data table has id as `table-id` you can try`#table-id.v-data-table .v-data-footer` to increase specificity.

If you are using older version of Vuetify then the class won't be `.v-data-footer`. It would be `.v-datatable__actions`